# facebook app access_token and friends birthday

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying to build a small website that will do the following:

1. customer should click  a "login with facebook" and assign a access token. the permissions i request are: 'email,user_about_me,user_birthday,user_relationship_details,user_status,publish_actions,friends_birthday,publish_stream,read_friendlists'
2. i create the customer on my db and save it's facebook id and the accessToken.
3. on my server, i run a cron job who pull list of friends, and with the APP access_token i call the graph api with something like this url: https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/friends?fields=birthday,name,email&access_token=MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN (not the token i pulled from the client since that's token should expire)

the problem is, that if i call this link with the customer access token i get all the details but if i call with the app access_token i get only the name and id and not the birthday and email. since i want to run my script every day and send greetings in the name of my customer to his friends when they have birthdays, i want to use the app access_token which should not expire. how can i achieve this method?

UPDATE:
it seems that the issue solved to me by requesting the long live access token with this method: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token, maybe it can save someone times